# <img> and <label> tag in same line

Tags: html, css

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC3. Following is my view page:

```
<div id="onsite" style="overflow:auto;margin-left:30px;">
    <img style="cursor:pointer;" id="imgminusOnsitewise" src="@Url.Content ("~/Content/Images/details_close.png")" alt="imgminusOnsitewise" title="Expand" /><label style="color:Green; font:bold 14px/30px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Onsite</label>
</div>
```

When I give like this image and label are in same line when I run the code in local machine. After deploying the same code to server, label displaying in next line of image. Another CSS property I need to add to get `<img>` and `<label>` tags which are inside `<div>` tag in same line?

Comment: What's the difference between the local rendering and the deployed rendering?  Are there any changes to the CSS on either environment?  Other differences in the markup?  Use your browser's debugging tools and compare both outputs.  Examine their markup and styling to look for differences.

Answer (score 0):

cheap and cheerful fix, try setting both elements display property to inline using style="display:inline;"

Comment: Dude by default `img` and `label` are inline elements.

Comment: yes but we don't know that other styles aren't being applied elsewhere so setting it on the elements should override any craziness

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the .css files are not equal

Try this:

```
<div id="onsite" style="overflow:auto;margin-left:30px;">
    <div style="float:left">
        <img style="cursor:pointer;" id="imgminusOnsitewise" src="@Url.Content ("~/Content/Images/details_close.png")" alt="imgminusOnsitewise" title="Expand" />
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; margin-left:10px">
        <label style="color:Green; font:bold 14px/30px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Onsite</label>
    </div> 
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
 </div>
```